# SSAS Last Year MTD Calculation Irregular Calnedar

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

I have a sales calendar where the calendars for a month change year to year.  The example is that September 2015 is defined as September 1 - September 30 but last year it ran from September 3 - September 30.
So when I want to compare this year MTD on 9/1/2015 should be compared to 9/3/2014.  I have all the dates in the time dimension, like LAST MTD Start and LAST MTD End, and put them in a hierarchy, DATE with LAST MTD START and LAST MTD END, and tried ancestor functions, like

```
WITH 
 MEMBER [Measures].LMTD AS 
    SUM(
       ANCESTOR(
         [Time].[LYMD_START].CURRENTMEMBER
        ,1
       )
      ,[Measures].[Volume]
    )
SELECT 
  [Measures].LMTD on 0
FROM  [myCUBE]
WHERE [Time].[DATE].&[2015-09-01T00:00:00];
```

But I only get back the current month's aggregated volume.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dimension with date, sales month, and sales year, the following should work. If you filter to 2015-09-01 (which is the first day of the 9th sales month) the this will step back one sales year and then find the first day of the 9th sales month (2014-09-03):

```
ParallelPeriod(
    [Date].[Sales Calendar].[Sales Year], 
    1, 
    [Date].[Sales Calendar].CurrentMember
   )
```

Then you want to sum up the days in that sales month through 2014-09-03:

```
Sum(
  PeriodsToDate(
    [Date].[Sales Calendar].[Sales Month],
    ParallelPeriod(
        [Date].[Sales Calendar].[Sales Year], 
        1, 
        [Date].[Sales Calendar].CurrentMember
       )
    ),
  [Measures].[Volume]
 )
```

So the hard work is in building the dimension with the right sales months. The MDX can just navigate that hierarchy.

Comment: Thank Greg.  What I ended up doing is creating separate hierarchy for each date I was looking for (MTD, YTD, Last Year MTD, etc.), looking up the start and end dates in the hierarchy for that I wanted to use, and then using the STRTOSET function to dynamically create the calculated member.  This technique was outlined in this blog post (https://ditchiecubeblog.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/multi-select-friendly-time-calculations-in-analysis-services/).

Comment: @TonyG. did Greg Galloway's answer answer your question? I realise from your comment it is not the approach you have implemented but did it answer the question?

Comment: @whytheq His answer was great but did not solve my issue so I guess no.  It's still a great answer to a common problem, just not mine.